# Compilation error when creating ISR(vect) interruption : multiple definition of `TIMER0_COMPA_vect'

Tags: c++, avr, isr, multiple-definition-error, atmega32

Good morning everyone i'm posting this here because i can't figure it out on my own. I've been trying to add ISR function in my project but it doesn't compile.

I work on Microship studio on an ATmega328p on a raw c++ project (NO ARDUINO).

I've been trying to add ISR(vect) interruption in my program but i can't manage to compile and i don't anderstand what i'm doing wrong.

In my code i'm using TIMER0_COMPA_vect but it also doesn't work with none of the 25 vectors in iom328p.h nor with _VECTOR(14).

Here's my code :

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

#define F_CPU 9999999

static unsigned long long tick = 0;

static void startup(){
    TCCR0B = 0x01; // set Prescaller
    OCR0A = 200;   //Set the flag trig at 200
    TIMSK0 = (1<<OCIE0A); //interrupt 
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){
    ;
}
```

Here is the error :

```
Error       ld returned 1 exit status
Error       multiple definition of `TIMER0_COMPA_vect'  config.h    23
Error       recipe for target 'project.elf' failed
```

Answer (score 2):

[I'm assuming that `config.h` is the name of the file you quoted in the question.]

If you've put the definition in a header file that's included in multiple compilation units, then the linker is noticing that it's been defined multiple times.  It's a violation of the [one-definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) in C++.

- You can *declare* the ISR in a header file, but the *definition* should be in an implementation file (`.cpp`, `.cc`, `.c`, etc.).
- If you don't need to declare it in the header file, then just move the entire function to an implementation file.
- If you must define it in a header file, then you can add `inline` to the function signature, which is a misleadingly named way around the one-definition rule.